# How to bind data from dropdown list in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new in asp.net core and try to develope an education projet (e-shop) with entity framework.
I have some problems with model binding.
I have 2 models: Product and Category.

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

ProductController:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(categoryRepo.Categories, "Id", "Name");

            return View("Edit", new Product());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int productId)
        {
            return View(repo.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repo.SaveProduct(product);
                TempData["Message"] = $"{product.Title} successfully saved";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(categoryRepo.Categories, "Id", "Name");
                return View(product);
            }

        }
```

Everything is ok with Create method in ProductController and getting categories to drop-down list in Edit.cshtml

```
@model Product
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add product";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Product" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Title"></label>
        <div>
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Title"></span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Description"></label>
        <div>
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Description"></span>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Description" cols="15" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Category"></label>
        <div>
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Category"></span>
        </div>
        <select asp-for="Category" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories">
            <option disabled>Choose the category</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Price"></label>
        <div>
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Price"></span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Price" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

But when I try to submit back the form to Edit method in ProductController.cs the Category field isn't binding to Product and I get just validation error "Choose the category".

Please help me with this issue!

P.S.
DbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options){ }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Implementation of IProductRepository

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private AppDbContext context;

        public EFProductRepository(AppDbContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }
        public IQueryable<Product> Products => context.Products.Include(p => p.Category);

        public void SaveProduct(Product product)
        {
            if (product.Id == 0)
            {
                context.Products.Add(product);
            }
            else
            {
                Product entry = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == product.Id);

                if (entry != null)
                {
                    entry.Title = product.Title;
                    entry.Description = product.Description;
                    entry.Category = product.Category;
                    entry.Price = product.Price;
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Implementation of ICategoryRepository

```
public class EFCategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
    {
        private AppDbContext context;

        public EFCategoryRepository(AppDbContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }
        public IQueryable<Category> Categories => context.Categories;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fix  ViewBag.Categories of the action

```
 ViewBag.Categories = categoryRepo.Categories
                     .Select( i=> new SelectListItem {
                      Value=i.Id.ToString(),
                      Text=i.Name 
                     }).ToList();
```

Add CategoryId to Product class, and check your Product fluent Apis. Should not be anything in Product about requied Category, changed everything to CategoryId.

```
public class Product
    {
       ...
        public int? CategoryId {get;set;}
        public  virtual Category Category { get; set; }
      ....

    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
    }
```

and fix the view

```
 <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. I debug post method Edit and in ModelState I see ValidationState invalid for Category. With CategoryId is everything ok.

Comment: @tiomkin Do you have fluent Api in your dbcontext? Pls post everything for Product

Comment: I've added to my question

Comment: @tiomkin Thanks, I updated my answer too.  But I still  can't see your Product fluent Api. It is the most important part.

Comment: ohh, thank you so much!! Really, i didn't remove [Required] from Category. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You've to add CategoryId object in Product, so your product class should be

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId {get;set;}
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

    }
```

And in your view page, category select element should be use CategoryId instead of Category in asp-for attribute
It should be like

```
 <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
```

Comment: you can alternatively use plain model instead of selectitemlist and use it at view side <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories,"Id", "Name"))" class="form-select border-0 shadow">
                        <option disabled selected>--Select Category</option>
                    </select>                         Other option is to create viewmodel instead and pass all models to that